Update the Kalman Filter in Simulink model
I want to creat a Filter in Simulink. For example:
filter = trackingKF('MotionModel', '2D Constant Acceleration', 'State', zeros(6, 1));

Then in simulink model, I want to update the filter and predict the states after receive feedback during the simulation. The function is defined as:
function predictedState = Predict(x,y)
    
    % Receive feedback about the present position
    presentPosition = [x;y]; 
    
    % Correct step: Update the filter with observed position
    correct(filter, presentPosition);
    
    % Predict future positions after receiving feedback
    predictedState = predict(filter);
 
end

My problem is: How to define this Filter in Simulink that can be updated by using 'correct' command, and how can I build a structure that can update this filter using my above function during my simulation.
Thank you for your helps !
I try to define the Kalman Filter in my Predict function but it seems not good because the filter need to be updated to become more precise. Can the callback function in Model Explorer give a help ?

Mathworks has many tutorials on Kalman Filters using Simulink (e.g. https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/state-estimation-using-time-varying-kalman-filter.html). Your question is probably too broad to be answered here; I would suggest working through the tutorials.

@ Dawson Beatty Thank for your consideration. I know almost tutorials of Mathworks about KF, but they always use the Kalman Filter block. I am trying to construct it through MATLAB function because I can custom deeper on the filter model. Moreover, I don't know the way to define an initial model in Simulink and update it during simulation (this KF problem is an example). Thanks for your help.
